# How to build a build.xml file to run a bat file or shell script

Tags: shell, unix, batch-file, ant, antbuilder

I have a  bat file and shell script which performs the same operation. Now i have create a ant build.xml file which would execute the shell script or bat file. How should i write my build.xml or how should i configure it ?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Use conditional targets

```
<condition property="windowsos">
  <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<condition property="linuxos">
  <os family="unix" />
</condition>

<target name="go" depends="go-windows,go-linux"/>

<target name="go-windows" if="windosos">
..
..
</target>

<target name="go-linux" if="windosos">
..
..
</target>
```

### Option 2: Use conditional exec task

```
<target name="go">
  <exec executable="doSomthing.exe" osfamily="windows"/>

  <exec executable="doSomthing" osfamily="unix"/>
</target>
```